# WebApi Url should allow special characters like forward slash(/) , ( and )

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-mvc-routing

Some of web api endpoints have strings as input parameters and some times I have to pass special characters like /,\,( and ). But, it is not allowing special characters because those has special functionalities. Is there any way solve this problem.

Comment: How about URL encoding?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way solve this problem.

No.

[(Please) Stop Using Unsafe Characters in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/). URLs are by definition machine readable. There are rules to follow about what can and cannot be part of a URL.

Although technically using unsafe characters is supposed to be possible through encoding, all bets are off that all browsers, web servers, and firewalls will treat them as "plain text" when encoded instead of assigning them special meaning. Some may just reject the URL entirely, considering it SPAM or attempted hacking.